# Can I use ElementTree to get the full structure of an XML file?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Suppose my xml looks like this:

```
<stuff>fee <i>italic</i> fie <b>bold</b> foe</stuff>
```

If I parse this with ElementTree, I can use `iter()` to access the sub elements, and I can use `itertext()` to access the text elements, but how can I access them both? In other words, I want to iterate through `<stuff>` and get:

```
text "fee "
element <i>
text " fie "
element <b>
text " foe"
```

Is this possible (and easy), or am I using the wrong parser?

Comment: You might also consider using `.xpath()`:  `from lxml import etree / stuff = etree.fromstring('<stuff>fee <i>italic</i> fie <b>bold</b> foe</stuff>') / for node in stuff.xpath("child::node()"): print type(node), node`

I realize that’s not the normal idiomatic ElementTree way to do things, and the case in the question is simple enough that I guess it doesn’t matter so much what you use; but in more complex cases when you want to, say, select just particular elements, or particular text nodes matching certain substrings, it can be a powerful way to grab them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the tails of all the subelements to get all the text for stuff:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring('<stuff>fee <i>italic</i> fie <b>bold</b> foe</stuff>')
>>> print('Text:', root.text)
>>> for child in root:
...     print('Element:', child.tag)
...     print('Text:', child.tail)
Text: fee 
Element: i
Text:  fie 
Element: b
Text:  foe
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for e in tree.iter():
  yield e
  try:
     yield e.text
  except:
     continue
```

Comment: Not quite, but you led me to the answer; I'll post it below.